# AseConnection.Open() throws AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, sybase, access-violation, sap-ase

A line of code that's been working for as long as I can remember has suddenly stopped working and it's now throwing an AccessViolationException:

**Exception:**

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that
other memory is corrupt.
Source=Sybase.Data.AseClient
StackTrace:
    at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnectionPool.ᜀ(AseConnection A_0)
    at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnectionPoolManager.ᜀ(String A_0, AseConnection A_1)
    at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseConnection.Open()
InnerException:
```

**Code:**

```
using (var connection = new AseConnection(this.ConnectionString))
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "select * from TABLE_NAME";
        command.Connection.Open();
        ...
```

I've rebooted my machine, checked for recent Windows Updates, ran CHKDSK, uninstalled and re-installed Sybase but nothing seems to work!

I'm targeting a Sybase 12.5.4 database using a 64bit Sybase 12.5.4 client with Sybase.Data.AseClient.dll referenced in my code (same version as Production code - which is working without issue) and sybdrvado11.dll is available when the application's running.  Literally *nothing* has changed since it was last working.

Using Toad, I'm still able to connect and interact with the database as well, so it looks like this issue is only affecting my code.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a database permissions issue relating to group membership...  I was removed the problem group and everything came to life again.

Answer (score 2):

Realise this is an ancient issue, but thought I'd share some insights I've had in this area.

There is a persistent underlying issue with the SAP/Sybase `AseClient` where, when connection pooling is enabled, it will attempt to get a connection from the pool. If none are available, it will attempt to create a new connection, unless there are already `Max Pool Size` connections in the pool.

In this case, instead of waiting, it will try to create a connection that overruns the bounds of the connection pool, overwriting protected memory and producing the error you have experienced above.

This issue exists even today.

Although the root cause in your case was a permissions issue, the `AccessViolationException` was caused by the connection pool - as can be seen from your stack trace.

We worked around it in some cases by disabling connection pooling - which crippled performance, and in other cases by setting a `Max Pool Size=1000` which hid it unless the ASE server was experiencing degradation sufficient to tie up 1000 connections. Neither approach is particularly satisfactory.

That instability was one of the motivations behind [an alternative AseClient](https://github.com/DataAction/AdoNetCore.AseClient) that we wrote and open sourced that also supports .NET Core.